# How do I only show values that end in a specific characters?

Tags: spotfire

In Spotfire, I have a list of codes that are formatted like the following:

> 4530, 4510, 4550, 6000|1
>
> 4530, 4510, 4710|3|327, 6000|1
>
> 4530, 4510, 4800
>
> 4850, 4530, 4510, 6000|1
>
> 4530, 4516, 4520, 4720
>
> 4530, 4516, 4520, 4720|351

I would like for the data to only contain values that end in `6000|1`.
How would I go about doing this in a custom expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following expression in a new calculated column:

```
If(Right([Column], 6) = "6000|1", "MATCH")
```

and then filter on your new column